# Downcasting a list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, downcast

How can I downcast a list of objects so that each of the objects in the list is downcast to an object of a derived class?

This is the scenario.

I have a base class with a `List` of base items, and two classes inheriting from it:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public List<BaseItem> items;
    protected BaseClass()
    {
        // some code to build list of items
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass : base() {}
}
public class AnotherDerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public AnotherDerivedClass : base() {}
}

public class BaseItem {}
public class DerivedItem : BaseItem {}
public class AnotherDerivedItem : BaseItem {}
```

The idea is to not have to duplicate the code needed to build the list of items. The `BaseItem` has all the basic stuff I need, and I can always downcast `BaseItem` to one of the derived items.

The problem arises when I have a list of them. The `List` of `BaseItem` is declared in the `BaseClass` because all the derived classes have to have it. But when accessing it at runtime I can't seem to be able to downcast to the derived class.

Comment: You should probably be looking in to Interfaces.

Comment: Or bog standard polymorphism: virtual methods in the base class, which you override in the derived classes. No downcasting required because you use the base class type to call the overridden methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
    var baseList = new List<BaseClass>();
    var derivedList = baseList.Cast<DerivedClass>();
```

Note: Having to downcast usually is a 'smell' and indicates that the inheritance hierarchy is wrong, or wrongly implemented. The idea of having a base class is that you can treat all subclasses as superclass without having to downcast to individual subclass types.

Instead of `Cast` you might want to use `OfType` to 'fish out' certain derived classes from a collection of superclasses. But again, there should be no need to do that.

Ask yourself, why you need to have a subclass - maybe you need to move some functionality to base class?

Comment: This one does exactly what I was asking for. But the other answers and comments are making me wonder if perhaps I could avoid doing this kind of thing altogether.

Comment: It started blowing up at runtime, saying it couldn't do the cast. In the meanwhile I lost my patience and went down the code duplication route...

Comment: It's because your collection contains other derived types as well. OfType will work in this situation.

Answer (score 6):

I believe what you want to do is use generics:

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T: BaseItem, new()
{
    public List<T> items;
    protected BaseClass()
    {
        items = new List<T>();
        T item = new T();
        item.SomePropertyOfBaseItem=something;
        items.Add(item);
    }
}

public class DerivedClass: BaseClass<DerivedItem>
```

This will cause the `items` in `DerivedClass` to be `List<DerivedItem>`. The `where` enforces that only types that derive from `BaseItem` can be used.

*edit*: "downcasting", casting a type to a derived type, isn't really what you are trying to do here. Your intent is that the derived list objects use a specific derived item type by design, and presumably you want to store instantiated objects of the derived type in your derived list class.

So, this could work just fine without using generics: the `List<BaseItem>` is perfectly capable of storing any items that derive from `BaseItem`. However, you would have to reference these objects from the list using casting (as described in the other answers) in order to access the derived properties. But that is simply "casting" an object to it's true type. Generics gives you a way to provide strongly typed access to these objects directly.

Basically, storing an object in a container that is a superclass of the object doesn't change anything about the object - it only changes the way your code can refer to it, by making it appear to be the simpler type from which it derives.

Comment: The problem here is that it's useful to have the items attribute in the BaseClass, because otherwise I wouldn't be able to have the constructor of the BaseClass building it.

Comment: Why not? What would your constructor do with a `List<BaseItem>` that it couldn't just as easily do with a `List<T>`? The compiler will actually treat `T` just like `BaseItem` in your base class because of the `where` clause.

Comment: Btw - generics are, possibly, the single most useful addition to C# since 1.0. I know, I'll have some disagreement from people who like linq, or perhaps `=`. But while you can create code that does the same thing using casting, using generics instead will make your code more readable, comprehensible, and bug resistant, by enabling you to strongly type internal members and return values.

Comment: @Firinha - see edit, I think I know why it didn't work for you. You just need to add a `new()` constraint to allow creating items of the generic type, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Zoo
{
     public List<Animal> items;
     protected BaseClass()
     {         // some code to build list of items     }
 }

public class PettingZoo : Zoo
{
     public PettingZoo : base() {}
}

public class CatComplex : Zoo
{
     public CatComplex : base() {}
}

public class Animal {}
public class Sheep : Animal {}
public class Tiger : Animal {}
```

...

```
PettingZoo myZoo = new PettingZoo();
myZoo.items.Add(new Tiger());
```

PettingZoo is not interchangeable with Zoo, as a PettingZoo should restrict the types of Animals.  As such, this design fails [the Liskov substitution principle](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html).

Comment: Bad examples. Your PettingZoo doesn't implement any restriction on the types of Animals, so PettingZoo and Zoo should be interchangeable. Follwing your link, the test implementation for the Square and Rectangle class hierarchy represents a programming error for the set_width() and set_height() methods. The functions in Square violate the overridden Rectangle methods by introducing undesired side effects, so of course the test will fail.

Comment: @Suncat2000 As such, this design fails the Liskov substitution principle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LINQ to iterate through the elements of the base class and downcast each element, like this:

```
var baseList = new List<BaseClass>();
var derivedList = new List<DerivedClass>();
baseList.ForEach(v => derivedList.Add((DerivedClass)v));
```

If you need to check the derived type of each element before casting:

```
var baseList = new List<BaseClass>();
var derivedList = new List<DerivedClass>();
baseList.OfType<DerivedClass>().ToList().ForEach(v => derivedList.Add(v));
```

For more information, take a look at the following articles:

- [DotNetPearls article on OfType](http://www.dotnetperls.com/oftype)
- [MSDN documentation on OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx)