# How to convert List<object> to List of something else at runtime?

Tags: c#

I have two lists.

```
List<string> listString;
List<int> listInt;
```

The input I get in is

```
List<object>
```

At runtime, is there a way to convert

```
List<object>
```

to another List?

Edit:
My question is how do I it at runtime. Not compile time.

Comment: Yes there is, but it of course depends on what exactly you want to do. What does your input contain? strings? binary data? ints? I mean, _how_ do you want to convert the `object` into an `int` or `string`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downcasting a list of objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234111/downcasting-a-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

```cs
List<string> listString = listObject.Cast<string>().ToList();
List<int> listInt = listObject.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.OfType()` filter to get the specific lists.

```
var all = new List<object>();
// add stuff

List<string> text = all.OfType<string>().ToList();
List<int> vals = all.OfType<int>().ToList();
```